# The commands runs and does what I want it to but still displays an error (in red highlight ) in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh, plink

In powershell, I ran a command to stop and start the linux server. When I run the command to start the server, the command does what I want but also output an error.  The displayed error:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Starting storms...rm-supervisor_1:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

The command:

```
 plink -ssh username@$SpoutIP -pw Password "sudo sh -c 'cd /root/docker/storm-supervisor/; ./start-all.sh'"
```

The command  "sudo sh -c 'cd /root/docker/storm-supervisor/; ./start-all.sh'" work since I tested the command on putty. It is obvious that the commands runs the way I want it to but why do I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I found out that I needed to make the command interactive by adding "-t".